# Why does '<<<' in Bash works only when a command is executed?

Tags: bash, shell

If I run the first command, it outputs `a="A", b="B"`, but if I run the second command, it doesn't output anything.

first

```sh
while read a && read b; do echo "a=$a, b=$b"; done <<<$(echo '["A", "B"]' | jq '.[]')
```

second

```sh
 while read a && read b; do echo "a=$a, b=$b"; done <<<"A B"
```

Why can't I read the string supplied unless it comes from a command output?

Comment: Use `read a b` in the second script to read two values on the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example, `read a` consumes the entire here string. `read b` has nothing left to read, so it fails. This causes the `while` loop condition to fail, which means the body is never executed.

The difference in the first command is that `jq` produces *two* lines of output, so each `read` command reads one of them. (The newlines separating them is preserved because the result of the command substitution is not subject to word-splitting, as the value of the here string.)

```
$ echo '["A", "B"]' | jq '.[]'
"A"
"B"
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not what's happening here. Your second attempt produces a single line, which is consumed by the first `read`; the second `read` then fails, which causes it to return an error, which causes `while` to not enter the loop.

The proper solution would look something like

```
while read -r a b; do
    echo "a='$a' b='$b'"
done <<<'"A" "B"'
```

and, for that matter, your first attempt should probably not use `<<<` at all;

```
while read -r a && read -r b; do
    echo "a='$a' b='$b'"
done < <(echo '["A", "B"]' | jq '.[]')
```

or

```
echo '["A", "B"]' | jq '.[]' |
while read -r a && read -r b; do
    echo "a='$a' b='$b'"
done
```

or, as astutely pointed out in a comment (-;

```
jq '.[]' <<<'["A", "B"]' |
while read -r a && read -r b; do
    echo "a='$a' b='$b'"
done
```

The `<<<` here-string syntax really only makes sense to use when what you have is actually already a string. Use a pipe or a process substitution to read something from a subprocess.

Comment: So, `jq '.[]' <<< '["A", "B"]'` (instead of `echo '["A", "B"]' | jq '.[]'`) would make sense, wouldn't it?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Yes, absolutely, good point!